# Scroll through a user control while timer is running

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

Whenever I click the area of the user control, it highlights the combobox, making it so that if I attempt to scroll to the bottom of the screen, it only scrolls through the combobox.

I tried putting `somelabel.focus()` in the click event for the user control. This kind of works. However, this does not allow me to scroll to a part of the control where `somelabel` is not visible, which seems a little strange to me. I obviously need to be able to scroll all the way to the bottom of the usercontrol.

Additional info: This is a winforms project, and the user control is running on a timer, where the only controls are the `combobox` and some `labels` that have their `.text` property updated every time the timer loops.

UPDATE: I tried disabling the timer, and it appears that after changing the focus to one of the labels, I am now able to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page. So it seems its an issue with the timer.

Here is some code that replicates the problem. If you click on the panel, it gains focus, but it will not let you scroll using the scrollwheel. **It will bring the top of the panel back to the top of the screen. If you don't turn on the timer, however, you can freely scroll.**

```
Public i As Integer
Public iString As String

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        iString = i.ToString()
        Label1.Text = iString
        Label2.Text = iString
        Label3.Text = iString
        Label4.Text = iString
        Label5.Text = iString
        i += 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.Click
        Panel1.Focus()
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think if you did set the [Control.TabStop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to False then focus or selection of a control disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `Panel` with `Dock=Fill` and `AutoScroll=true` in which you insert your controls. Then add the click event for the panel:

```
private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl = panel1;
}
```

This way if you click inside the panel (which fills the whole `UserControl`), the panel will be active and you can scroll. This won't affect controls inside the panel so you can work with them in the usual way.

Comment: That gives the panel focus. The new problem is for some reason, while the timer is running, if I use the scrollwheel to scroll, it brings me back to the top of the usercontrol.

Comment: I tested your code in C# and it also works with the timer for me. I can scroll with mousewheel without problems. I also tested several intervals like 10, 100 or 1000.

Comment: No. Thats some complete code that does exactly what my full application does. With your code, when the program starts, I can click the form and scroll to the bottom. If I click the combobox first then click somewhere else in the control, the panel will gain focus, however, I can't freely scroll with the scrollwheel. It will jump back to the top of the usercontrol unless the timer is off.

Comment: Strange. I now created a VB.net project and used exactly your code. But I don't have your problem. How do you integrate your `UserControl` into your application? Is it part of a form? Does it fill the entire form? Where are the combo box and labels located inside your control?

Comment: I'm so dumb sometimes. I got it to work now. I put the panel in and sent it to back, which didn't put the controls **on** the panel, just over or something like that. Once I placed my controls on the panel, it worked perfectly. Sorry for the trouble.